# Glove word embedding model parameters using tex2vec in R, and display training output (epochs) after every n iterations

Tags: r, word2vec, text2vec, glove

I am using text2vec package in R for training word embedding (Glove Model) as:

```
library(text2vec)
library(tm)

prep_fun = tolower
tok_fun = word_tokenizer
tokens = docs %>%  # docs: a collection of text documents  
prep_fun %>% 
tok_fun

it = itoken(tokens, progressbar = FALSE)

stopword <- tm::stopwords("SMART")
vocab = create_vocabulary(it,stopwords=stopword) 

vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(vocab)

tcm <- create_tcm(it, vectorizer, skip_grams_window = 6)

x_max <- min(50,max(10,ceiling(length(vocab$doc_count)/100)))
glove_model <- GlobalVectors$new(word_vectors_size = 200, vocabulary = vocab, x_max = x_max,learning_rate = 0.1) 

word_vectors <- glove_model$fit_transform(tcm, n_iter = 1000, convergence_tol = 0.001)
```

When I run this code I get the following output:
[image]

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to have output after every n iterations, i.e. output for epoch 50, 100, 150 and so on.
2. Any suggestion for optimal values for word_vectors_size, x_max and learning_rate? for example for 10,000 documents, what is the best value for those parameters?

I appreciate your response.

Many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a member of the `GlobalVectors` class called `n_dump_every`. You can set it to some number and the history of word embeddings will be saved. Then it can be retrieved with `get_history()` function

```
glove_model <- GlobalVectors$new(word_vectors_size = 200, vocabulary = vocab, x_max = 100,learning_rate = 0.1) 
glove_model$n_dump_every = 10
word_vectors <- glove_model$fit_transform(tcm, n_iter = 1000, convergence_tol = 0.001)
trace = glove_model$get_history()
```

Regarding second question -

- you may try to vary learning rate a bit (usually decrease), but default one should be ok (keep track of the value of cost function).
- the more data you have the larger value you can provide for `word_vectors_size`. For wikipedia size 300 is usually enough. For smaller datasets you may start with 20-50. You really need to experiment with this.

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitriy for your prompt reply.

Comment: glove_model$get_history() is very useful to save outputs. You have n_check_convergence in lda model, so one can see convergence and epochs after every n iterations. Do you have a similar thing in Glove model to filter R console dispaly? Thanks.